# Append to query-string with the same key

Tags: grails, query-string

I am trying to add some parts to a query-string with the same key.

I have a url like `http://server.com/search/result?query=hello` with some controls that should add a `collaborator` to the query-string.

This is done with this:

```
<g:link action="result" params="${params + ['collaborator': collaborator.id]}">${collaborator.name}</g:link>
```

Which returns: `http://server.com/search/?query=hello&collaborator=<id>`.

This is all good, but its possible to choose more collaborators. How do I append another `&collaborator=<id>` to the query?

I have tried various methods like `${params + [params.collaborator + collaborator.id]}`, but this only puts them in one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**gsp:**

```
<g:link action="result" params="${params + ['collaborator': params.list('collaborator') + [collaborator.id]]}">${collaborator.name}</g:link>
```

**action:**

```
List collaboratorList = params.list('collaborator')
//Your operations on this list
```